# Typescript websocket

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, next.js

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
var ws = new WebSocket(
  "wss://exemple.com/?user=data",
  {
    credentials: "omit",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0",
      Accept: "*/*",
      "Accept-Language": "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
      "Sec-WebSocket-Version": "13",
      "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions": "permessage-deflate",

      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "websocket",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "websocket",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
      "Sec-GPC": "1",
      Pragma: "no-cache",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    },
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
  }
);

ws.on("message", function (data, flags) {
//do some stufff with the data
}
```

Here is my code(in regular javascirpt) and i wanted to implement this code in my NextJs project (in TS) and it give me this errror :

```
Argument of type '{ credentials: string; headers: { "User-Agent": string; Accept: string; "Accept-Language": string; "Sec-WebSocket-Version": string; "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions": string; "Sec-Fetch-Dest": string; "Sec-Fetch-Mode": string; "Sec-Fetch-Site": string; "Sec-GPC": string; Pragma: string; "Cache-Control": string; }; method: ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'credentials' does not exist in type 'string[]'.ts(2345)
```

tried import { WebsocketBuilder } from "websocket-ts";
and wasnt able to make it work either.

npm i @types/ws fixed the issue thank you:)

Comment: have you installed the [`ws` module types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ws)?

Comment: @about14sheep i just did : npm i @types/ws and  it works but typescript still show me errors in my code but the code run. The error still persist.

Comment: what do you mean the code runs but typescript shows errors?

Comment: The second argument is a list of protocols.

Comment: it somehow dont show anymore i think it was VS code the issue. Now i wanna know how can i use that WebSocket in my nextjs project. (its a stream infinite of data)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.